# spaces in url redirects to default website, how can I change the root?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, root

If the selected value has a space, it get redirected to default website.

This is the page code.

```
Response.Redirect("~/tsAdmin/Marketing/OffersEdit.aspx?type=" + Server.UrlEncode(OfferTypeDropDownList.SelectedValue))
```

This will work

```
localhost:8011/tsAdmin/Marketing/OffersEdit.aspx?type=Shipping
```

But this will not work

```
localhost:8011/tsadmin/marketing/offersedit.aspx?type=buy%20x%20get%20y%20by%20category
```

it get redirected to `localhost/bvadmin/marketing/offersedit.aspx?type=buy%20x%20get%20y%20by%20category`

I'm assuming this is an IIS settings or in web.config.

Answer (score 1):

This was a setting in IIS. Needed to add .aspx pages as a recognized page.

Still not sure why it busted only when the param had a space, but its working now.